# The view admin panel.views.create category didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I dont know why i am getting this error I am trying build an admin panel.So I am trying to make create category functionality after coding all the functionalities i got stuck in this error

Here is my view.py

```
def createcategory(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    createcat = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if createcat.is_valid():
        cat_name = createcat.cleaned_data['category_name']
        cat_image = createcat.cleaned_data['category_image']
        insert_cat = CategoryModel(
            category_name=cat_name, category_image=cat_image)
        insert_cat.save()
        create2 = CategoryForm()
        return render(request, 'createcat.html', {'create2': createcat})
    else:
        createcat = CategoryForm()
    all_categories = CategoryModel.object.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Here is my models.py

```
class CategoryModel(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You only return at one condition, if it's at `POST`, else you don't. so please add a default return at the end.

just like:

```
if `POST`:
  ...
  return render(request, 'createcat.html', {'create2': createcat})
else:
  return render(request, 'default.html')
```

PS: using the below code format indention:

```
def createcategory(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        createcat = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if createcat.is_valid():
            cat_name = createcat.cleaned_data['category_name']
            cat_image = createcat.cleaned_data['category_image']
            insert_cat = CategoryModel(
                category_name=cat_name, category_image=cat_image)
            insert_cat.save()
            create2 = CategoryForm()
            return render(request, 'createcat.html', {'create2': createcat})
        else:
            createcat = CategoryForm()
        all_categories = CategoryModel.object.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
    # print("test")
```

PS2: Want to show form.

```
def createcategory(request):
    createcat = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # put your form here
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if createcat.is_valid():
            cat_name = createcat.cleaned_data['category_name']
            cat_image = createcat.cleaned_data['category_image']
            insert_cat = CategoryModel(
                category_name=cat_name, category_image=cat_image)
            insert_cat.save()
            create2 = CategoryForm()
            return render(request, 'createcat.html', {'create2': createcat})
        all_categories = CategoryModel.object.all() # make sure you know this line.
    return render(request, 'index.html', createcat) # put your empty form here
```

Comment: @GadgetNGadgetHQ Can you update your post with your latest code?

Comment: @GadgetNGadgetHQ try to using my post

Comment: Can you just put a `print("test")` at the end of this function? see if you can get there. As I do on my posted, you should uncomment that line.

Comment: its showing the index.html page but not showing the form

Comment: Sure! Because you try to visit your url by using `GET` method.

Comment: Sorry! it's another question! Check PS2

Answer (score 0):

I am giving the category model I created in the code example below as an example. Which model category you create is very important.

You also need to save the model you created in admin.py.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def task_count(self):
        return self.task.count()

class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='TaskUser')  # user
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Task Title')
    content = RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Task Date')
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="task")
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see I add a category field in the task model.

views.py

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'task/index.html'
    model = Task
    context_object_name = 'task'

    # paginate_by = 7

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

class CategoryDetail(ListView):  
    model = Task  
    template_name = 'category/category_detail.html'  
    context_object_name = 'task'  

    # paginate_by = 3

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category,
                                          pk=self.kwargs['pk'])  
        return Task.objects.filter(category=self.category).order_by('-id')  

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        # context['category'] = self.category
        return context
```

Finally, I am registering in admin.py.

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Task)
admin.site.register(Category)
```

I hope it helped.